# How to rename files of a SharePoint library while downloading to local drive

Tags: powershell

I have sharepoint library as below:
SP Library: "Test"

Folder1

```
  File1

  Folder2

     File1

  Folder3

     File2
```

I need as below in my local folder:
Local folder: "c:\"

Folder1

```
   abc0001_File1
   abc0002_File1
   abc0002_File2
```

Is there any powershell script by which I can rename files of a SharePoint library while downloading to local drive.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this

```
$webUrl = "http://sp2013-sp/Test"
$rootFolderUrl = "Shared%20Documents"
$destinationfolder= "c:/test"

function BuildPrefix($folderName, $previousPrefix) {
    return $previousPrefix + "abc" + $folderName + "_"
}
function isHidden($folder) {
    $attribs = $folder.Properties["vti_winfileattribs"]
    if ($attribs -eq $null) {
        return $false
    }
    $attribs = [Convert]::ToInt64($attribs, 16)
    return ($attribs -band 2) -eq 2
}
function ProcessFolder($folder, $prefix) {
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
            $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
            $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $prefix + $file.Name), Create
            $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
            $writer.write($binary)
            $writer.Close()
        }
    foreach ($subFolder in $folder.SubFolders) {
        if (isHidden $subFolder) {
            continue
        }
        $newPrefix = BuildPrefix $subFolder.Name $prefix
            ProcessFolder $subFolder $newPrefix
    }
}

if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
{
    New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory | Out-Null
}

$gc = Start-SPAssignment
$web = $gc |Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$folder = $web.GetFolder($rootFolderUrl )

ProcessFolder $folder "" 

Stop-SPAssignment $gc
```